# How do I include double quotation mark in a concatenated string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, string, concatenation

I have been unable to find a resource that shows how to add double quotation marks to a concatenated excel string. For example if I would like to represent **72 inches** as **72"** in a string the added double quotation marks breaks the concatenate string. to overcome this, I initially tried `=...&"&...` as well as `=...&\"&...` and `=...&'"'&...`- Neither are effective.

How do I get the double quotation mark included within the concatenated string?

Comment: @Tetsujin that may be the real reason I can't find what i want

Comment: You could use the proper symbol for inches, which is the *double prime* (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2033/index.htm) in which case it's just something like this: `=A1 & "″"`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is fairly simple, and counter intuitive and was only able to find it from excel suggesting the correct answer. To insert a double quotation mark, simply concatenate four double quotation marks to your string:

`=...&""""&...`

e.g. `=""""`returns `"` and  `=72&""""&" text"` returns `72" text`

Altenatively  you can use `CHAR(34)`

e.g. `=CHAR(34)`returns `"` and  `=72&CHAR(34)&" text"` returns `72" text`

Comment: You don't need a separate string, you can include `""` in any string and it will result in a `"` in the containing string.

Put another way, if you put consecutive two strings they will be joined with a quote; `"one""two"` is interpreted as a string containing `one"two`